# emacs syntax highlighting fails on my SSH client

Tags: ssh, terminal, emacs, syntax-highlighting

I need to connect to a remote server by SSH to edit some documents. When I work at home, I SSH to the remote server using SSH Secure Shell and open `emacs`, but it doesn't fully highlight documents as I want:

[image: Screenshot of emacs on this server]

Is there any way to fix it so that syntax highlighting works like when I ssh through Cygwin?

[image: Screenshot of emacs on Cygwin]

SSH Secure Shell only has a problem with emacs; everything else works fine.

[image: Syntax highlight works for bash]

Comment: When you ssh to a server and start up emacs, it will source the configuration file `~/.emacs` on the server. If you don't have one there, it may be the problem. Just copy it from your local machine.

Comment: What is the value for $TERM in both?

Comment: @symcbean On my SSH client, the $TERM has the value of `vt220`. When I change its value by executing `export TERM=ansi`, emacs fully highlights documents. Thank you!

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using? On Windows, I recommend using [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/).

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Gilles' line of thought, I'd suggest using Cygwin's MinTTY terminal instead of the Windows console-based one. It uses PuTTY's engine and offers a much, much better experience.

Answer (score 0):

see if `M-x font-lock-mode` fixes this for you.  if it does, but `(global-font-lock-mode 1)` into your .emacs file

Answer (score 0):

[Suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28818/emacs-syntax-highlighting-fails-on-my-ssh-client#comment38790_28818) from symcbean comment [solved](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28818/emacs-syntax-highlighting-fails-on-my-ssh-client#comment38810_28818) the problem, but there is one interesting possibility.

Why open Emacs in ssh if you can open ssh in Emacs? ;) If you have [TrampMode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode) which is part of standard Emacs installation you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> and enter `/ssh:hostname:filename` (you can use Tab completion) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. After that you will be prompted for password to remote host and file will be opened.

This should work for your problem as Emacs is opened on local machine. Next advantage is that there is no need to have configs for Emacs (end even Emacs) on remote machine.