# Autocompletion and coloring not working, when using ssh in emacs shell

Tags: shell, ssh, terminal, emacs

I'm connecting to remote server using `emacs shell`.
Emacs shell displays directory listings with proper coloring and auto completion when working with local machine.

But when I use `ssh` the autocompletion and coloring are gone. Same holds for `eshell`.

Is there a way to fix this without resorting to `M-x term`? Because emacs keys don't work in `term` which is a real productivity killer.

There is a similar question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28818/19506). But that is rather about emacs in SSH instead of SSH in emacs.

Answer (score 0):

In a `*shell*` or eshell buffer, Emacs performs file completion on its own, by looking at the local filesystem. This can't work if you're logged in to a remote machine over SSH.

In order to get completion of remote files, Emacs would have to let the shell handle the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. But Emacs's handling of <kbd>Tab</kbd> and other keys is what distinguishes `*shell*` from `*term*`.

In eshell, you can access remote directories via [Tramp](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/). For example, `cd /servername:/remote/path` gives you a shell in a remote directory accessed over SSH. Completion works if you do the remote connection this way.